# BlueJ: invalid cen header

Tags: java, bluej

I wanted to install BlueJ on my home PC and create a class. When I created it and pressed "compile" it just gives the error: `cannot access unnamed package: invalid CEN header (unsupported compression method:9)`

[image: Error Message]

I tried reinstalling BlueJ, downgrading java 17 -> 13, rebooting my PC and creating a new class in a new project.

Comment: It's might not be helpful but why don't you try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ ?
I think it's more popular than BlueJ and you might find more information on it.

Comment: @VitalyChura thanks, I know about eclipse/vscode and all the other "IDE's", but I need BlueJ for my classes.